# MongoClient PHP install on localhost

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to set up Mongo Client on my local machine. I use MAMP to run the Apache/PHP server.

I have installed Mongo using `sudo pecl install mongo` and it has succesfully installed (I receive the error `pecl/mongo is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.6.5`). I have then edited the php.ini line in MAMP to add `extension=php_mongo.dll` and also tried `extension=mongo.so`. In all cases I receive the error:

`Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in ....`

Any my phpinfo() file does not contain any reference to mongo.

Is there anything else to be checking to make sure it has installed correctly? Or to find why it isnt working?

Answer (score 1):

Have you started the ***mongod*** daemon ?

```
$ ps -ef | grep mongo
mongodb   1240     1  0  2014 ?        05:25:28 /usr/sbin/mongod --quiet -f /etc/mongodb.conf
```

If no output try:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb start
```

Can you connect from the command line eg.

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
connecting to: test
> show dbs
...
> exit
```

Is the ***mongo.so*** extension installed eg.

```
$ php -i 2>/dev/null | egrep "^extension_dir =>" 
extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php5/extensions => /usr/lib64/php5/extensions
$ ls /usr/lib64/php5/extensions | grep mongo
mongo.so
$
```

Is the extension loaded eg.

```
$ php -i 2>/dev/null | grep /php.ini
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
$ grep extension /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Comment: `$ ps -ef | grep mongo` produces:
`502 25320 24670   0 11:13am ttys000    0:00.00 grep mongo`

`sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb start` produces: `sudo: /etc/init.d/mongodb: command not found`

`$ mongo` produces: -bash: mongo: command not found

mongo.so extension check all checks out fine

`$ php -i 2>/dev/null | grep /php.ini` outputs nothing

Comment: @dojogeorge that's showing you ***mongod*** hasn't been started, go find the directory mongodb has been installed into and as a stopgap do a: $ ./mongod    There's a useful set of instructions on the 10Gen site: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/